# Optimizing string manipulations in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset of 10M records where the first step is to clean the data and make the length of the words in the dataset less than 400 if any. Can this be done faster in raw form without using numba /dask or other multiprocessing libraries?

```
from cleantext import clean
def func_vect(val):
    temp=clean(val,no_line_breaks=True,no_urls=True,no_emails=True,lower=True).split()

    if len(temp)<=400:
        return " ".join(u for u in temp if len(u)<=15)

    else:
        return " ".join(u for u in temp[:175]+temp[-175:] if len(u)<=15)

ufunc_vec=np.vectorize(func_vect,otypes=[str])
```

Comment: why not use np.select(condition, choice) for your if else condition. it should speed it up

Comment: can you give an example by code? I tried np.select but there in the else condition i will have to split the text twice ,right?

Comment: pretty difficult to give you a code without the data. but the idea is to lose your loops and optimise it with numpy.

Comment: DO NOT USE `np.vectorize` in hope of speeding up code.  In `pandas` string values are stored as Python strings in an object dtype Series.  `pandas` does have ways of applying string methods to Series.  `numpy` does not do anything fast or fancy with strings.

Answer (score -1):

This might work:

```py
df['truncated_string'] = df['string'].str[:400]
```

Comment: I want to first clean the text and then take the first 175 words and the last 175 words and then join them and feed that as an input to ML model.

Comment: Is there a reason why cleaning cannot be done on a column? Something like `df['clean_string'] = df['dirty_string'].appy(cleaning_func)`?

Comment: For less computation time I have made a function. Apply will also work for the aforementioned case but with more time.